# Pouring drainage channel right next to foundation, how to protect the foundation?

Tags: concrete, drainage, french-drain

Ugh.  How can I arrange details on this concrete pour, to not damage the foundation later?

[image: Concrete pour right up to foundation]

[image]

This is San Francisco Bay area (no freezing).  The visible clay pipe is a high volume gravity drain from the driveway and thus unfortunately sets the vertical level of things (it was somebody's DIY project in 1950). This drain had been blocked until just last week, with a soil having built up to block the drain.

The house is half cripple wall, half slab.  This is the slab section.

There's also a low volume french drain outlet dumping in the same area.  The idea is to have the water rather than soaking in, sheet out over the existing concrete to the neighbors (that neighbor rejected the idea of piping downhill through their property to the curb, so I'm doing the best I can).

The sill plate is about an inch above the stucco bottom edge.
I'm concerned about pouring directly against the foundation.
The local soils are expansive clay, and I know there will be relative motion over time.  The right pour is, to me, murky.  Your thoughts?